# sql output clause error

Tags: sql, sql-server, clause

t1 has an automatically generated primary key called `pkId`

```
INSERT INTO t1( title, summary)
OUTPUT inserted.pkId, t2.id INTO @IdTable(New_Id, Old_Id)
SELECT t2.title, t2.summary
FROM t2
```

Can someone please tell me why this doesn't work?

I'm getting the error The multi-part identifier "t2.id" could not be bound.

Comment: Please tag this with the RDBMS you're using. This isn't standard SQL.

Comment: It doesn't work because you are not selecting `t2.id` in your `SELECT`statement. To make it work, you should add `t2.id`to your statement but that would also require you to `INSERT` this ID in `t1`wich (I assume) is not what you need. *I'm still pondering on how to resolve that elegantly.*

Comment: Exactly!  I cannot insert t2.id but i do need to insert it into @IdTable.  So how do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Comments

> It doesn't work because you are not selecting t2.id in your 
>   SELECT statement. To make it work, you should add t2.id to your
>   statement but that would also require you to INSERT this ID in t1 which
>   (I assume) is not what you need. I'm still pondering on how to resolve
>   that elegantly.

Not an elegant solution but the easiest might be to

- Add a dummy `t2ID` column to `t1`
- Alter your `INSERT` to include the `t2ID` (not using an `OUTPUT` clause)
- Select all new values into your `@IdTable`
- Remove the dummy column

#### SQL Script

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD COLUMN t2ID INTEGER NULL
GO

INSERT INTO t1( title, summary, t2ID)
SELECT t2.title, t2.summary, t2.ID
FROM t2

INSERT INTO @IdTable
SELECT pkID, t2ID
FROM   t1
WHERE  t2ID IS NOT NULL
GO

ALTER TABLE t1 DROP COLUMN t2ID
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't get the values from t2 in the OUTPUT clause on INSERT (you can for UPDATE and DELETE).

[From MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

> from_table_name
>
> Is a column prefix that specifies a table included in the FROM clause of a DELETE, UPDATE, or MERGE statement that is used to specify the rows to update or delete.

Note that INSERT isn't mentioned

You'd have to

- try [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) (I can't sorry) if you have SQL Server 2008+
- use another column and JOIN back later.